# Automation of release and dependency management

Tags: maven, jenkins, bitbucket

I have a maven project(main) with dependency A(com.util.myutil version 0.0.1).
When there is an update on myutil a new version would be released(0.0.2). Now the main project needs to be updated with the dependency 0.0.2. Can this be achieved via maven/jenkins/bitbucket. Currently we are manually changing the version and committing to bitbucket. I want this to be automated.

This would help to great extent since we have a lot of nested dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If two projects should be always built together, think about establishing ab multi-module project.

If this is not the way for you: You can use Maven goals like `versions:use-latest-releases` to update all dependencies in a POM.